# mysql update not working.. needs help on update code

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using $_POST to data to my php page to update the mysql database. I'm trying to use the customer id to pick the row and update the company name and fname(firstname). When I figure this out, I'll add the rest to be updated. I've also included what I've tried via the "//" Thank you

```
-----dbconnect-----
$id= $_POST['id'];
$company= $_POST['company'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];

echo $id;
echo $company;
echo $fname;
//$sql = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE customer SET company = $company WHERE id= '.$id.'")
//$sql = "UPDATE customer SET company ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company'])."WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'";
$sql = "UPDATE customer SET company = $company WHERE id= '1'";
mysqli_select_db('customer');
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $con );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: strings must be enclosed in quotes `SET company = '$company'`. Make sure to sanitize user data.

Comment: if company is a string you are missing quotes

Comment: 1llJames Could not update data:

Comment: it shows the id=1 then ll=for the company name then James=fname then the error

Comment: [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.select-db.php) requires **2** arguments ~ *bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )*

Comment: @sean I changed that and the error still pops up. Any other ideas? Thank you for helping

Comment: You're using mysqli, that's great. You should use a parameterized prepared statement like `$sql = "UPDATE customer SET company = ? WHERE id= ?";` and bind your input values to these placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a few assumptions here but try this out...

```
// make mysqli throw exceptions on error
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// assuming your connection looks something like this
// you can pass the database name as the fourth argument instead of using select_db()
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'customer');

// $id = $_POST['id'], etc

// use a prepared statement with parameter placeholders.
// for more info see http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE customer SET company = ? WHERE id = ?');

// bind parameter variables and execute
$stmt->bind_param('si', $company, $id);
$stmt->execute();

echo 'Updated data successfully', PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you Phil for the help. I have never used prepared statements and now have something to  add to my limited arsenal and will need to keep reading on them. Thank you again